# CSS- How to align Checkbox and dropdown menu on same line when clicked?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

In the code below there is a Checkbox "Allow", when I click on checkbox, the dropdown appears. Problem is they are not aligned. I want dropdown at on same line as Checkbox. How can I achieve this?

Below is the code

```
<div fxLayout="row">
                        <mat-checkbox formControlName="allow"
                            >Allow</mat-checkbox
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div
                        *ngIf="form2.value.extendedProperties.allow"
                        fxLayout="row"
                        fxLayoutAlign="start center"
                        class="full-width"
                        fxLayoutGap="16px"
                    >
                        <mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
                            <mat-select placeholder="Fee" formControlName="type">
                                <mat-option
                                    *ngFor="let ct of type.values"
                                    [value]="ct"
                                    >{{ type.descriptions[ct] }}</mat-option
                                >
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-form-field
                            fxFlex="40"
                            *ngIf="
                                form2.value.extendedProperties.type ==
                                type.nf
                            "
                        >
                            <mat-select placeholder="Select Nomination Fee" formControlName="nf">
                                <mat-option [value]="0">None</mat-option>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let fee of fees" [value]="fee.id">
                                    {{ fee.name }}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-checkbox
                            fxFlex="40"
                            *ngIf="
                                form2.value.extendedProperties.type ==
                                type.classEntryFee
                            "
                            formControlName="refund"
                        >
                            Refund
                        </mat-checkbox>
                    </div>
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]